# Save attachment IMAP and PHP

Tags: php, file, imap, email-attachments

I am using below code  to save imap attachment.

```
  $s = imap_fetchstructure($mbox,$mid);
    $attachments = array();
    if(isset($s->parts) && count($s->parts)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($s->parts); $i++)    
            if($s->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                foreach($s->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($s->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                foreach($s->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            
            if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($this->connection,$mid, $i+1);
                if($s->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
                elseif($s->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i am not getting attachment in a proper format.Attachment data is not readable

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [is_attachment] => 1 [filename] => clouds-5784152_640 (1).jpg [name] => clouds-5784152_640 (1).jpg [attachment] => ����JFIF��C !"$"$��C����"�������d3��̆�-RYnw��DFh���6S7J���i�iн3�t'��kWn��Ι�k�i���h��5�K�)B�Ն�� vI+��)�2W� ��)�28D�)c�W���H-AY!I@ҤV��T�B�R��SE� �R^�f����#�E��j��x�ڙӀ�s(����������:�W[˯8٢&.�^E���n�"3��G����\Z���"ꨪ�b�^�j��!����PCP�jL�M��݉(�Ւk�)��N}[�v;������*��}3�Z��*�d�}T���ǘ�ߓQ���מ��8�y�������R�pk-enՐ5�+L�M3�\P������b<)AKe�,RHV,!W���WQj�*�1�f���ޗ��*5������� h�>�W$b�siF�KA�癸�ds�u����YYcU��ڧY�Eg�A3�@Y������qל =��n��Hْ�hՙh�H��m�aiC����H��,��E%f�e��7㬮�&�u��,�3͆�Qs7��X������sՉ���1��j�JGm�e�t23��_)\J�cFB&2��z!dKk�[ͪ��0�VAa�#�Re@@�!B0�<�Yb�Lt:�_�S^�j�e�Z���ͼKq׹��F�}~z����tj���H���轳\۳��g�?[��M]���c9WGo�gU�q���EmG��V��a���J9�4�oX�_�xe�(��[de�d�:�1�ʷ�e�@�@4&��9�/F�GuY��+����t�=U;-f�m��m���Շ��h͝n9�k�U�LK*�t1�g�O'��z_)=>Ow_����u|��k>���~z������N��]ec_9��l�Ȕ��XN�T=��%�]��=�i� em�� ��)��B�<��#���:Cx�վ�R�d��MYe7{Z����kJ�s�9a;4y�sGY3�Y��r���Q��\�n@��&�6�gB�]k���[��َ��y6����^S*�8�Sx�)���MK� ��k*�d=0H��v�l�J��F�o�:� qt��;`�ۍgv��h��^^��[)> ��d5`S,C�,]0ۻ~�=w��׺�ΒG>nR�z�&�{���ue�_d�YҎp��ktq �Fl�� ��k6]E�����`}Z׌�� �м�ݚu�l���}��G��:yV�v㧗��Pt�ݦ�E�g��^m=9�S�:q�M�'t� m��H�x���Tm[X�SۢqY�����[��e�Wcӽ]�y�S�56V8�jo�ʽ����TY���f����D�V����T��ߤy3�X���:���Sx��u����L��ðW��҃|]�i�]��3Q���YӐ������Ȓ4�A�!`�<}#_���s�2�=�i�ÃF�8n�<�ѳC��u�7�N�'#��g|��h,�k�~����k�2��8����P<���N��>ޭ��3ѓ%� ��t����T�N��N�h�>���W`��ے����B��TEH�%c PВ4��j�iJ��jZ����Çͯ�����<�CWv�z:�8���v����U/G����OA�|��/�Ҽם��������Tٸ�uZ>��~#�ݾ���˧������q��}Oo�������翦�������_|8�Q��=)ϻ>�t�fd�5����ڲW���V�ki����K�k-��E���X���<<�{�5N�k �0V�.is�{�h�wT��nK3��sv�V �t���ĳD.mҖ�M��^��Tu����W"��q�F�c8|�˭f,l��Kk㚣s�-de� jܒ���i��A�ɥ�a�㕪�Ev.f�r��� VX���*&�L���3����3Zt�Ut�ι��ߗ�����*�h*�٢�WkՆ�1�޺�K�}E�65���{|�m^���~uZ%�v�M�����:U��a��K����c��i�q�>>������',�V���5�!�VWe���-o\�l���W�[.�ʆ�V�Mt����ˊ����F���7mç���������7^�l�p�?��g����K�s=����P��>��=lL����Ιބ�F��gL��d (k�uk����n�uW�C���U���=? ��/9� i�����u�)D�j��z��jy������$�%K�I�Vs�R��u��u����_[W�M�^��emEDcɴ����q1��'���ɟi��2Ѫ��{�P�q(�6�(�DS'.���&E���7���(���q���[+���\�X����O�jBm�� ����'��q��<�-(������Eme�K��ءjJ�B�U����6�Jފ{^���df�r��9��55T���tK .��  ��N�r�6qb��rbʩF:��Ϫ4�1���;�0k��,nB�ńXh�v���'�'tt2�{;��g&9��'~�Q_�EQG�]������H�&���d�OA�B^#�,LXz��1����a?��G����o���c��r�d�E�.�?�|�u�z\�Ń�r�~oQ�(�8w�(�g���i�>[G`�]L$�fw��qICU��9㉓�4qy>WI G$ ١�cսP������(����p8.��HZ��ϞiDq"�_��uژ���6�>e�.>6��?��4���"�#������)����j<�/�̈3���)"?���mbr�Y�������Ώ ��)F/�SǓX�44=���(��hhc���BBB���h���E�/7� ��pD��E$��]�$W\v��18t�0}?��]VG�u��(rn<8�;����Đ�F�E+M�Og'�����N/����z�8�Q�5�zLk�u��C[厧=�]��q����|�ÊG�q8�Y��Xر�)g�ht�o�����r3���1{�H�,qI�d��z1�3����덜>��h�w[!�g���,R����"УG~�M�� ��$2\�W�M�C]r9�e��� �^�x����_,5������x��N��BX[��O*�yG�G9�\��G�,y��6ћ>]@���cq�HIH���R���u#���f�c9~E��1ɞy\����.�D8���a����rE���dgk_�e�MT2���K4���)�������'u���r��B���u�L�~'�T���d#(6D��'�إ�G+i+%���<����_j]���\�e���X�8�͔�o˜5fy�����E��-�cG��8wT$tc�(?'��|���W��C��ץm[8���G��O�>p�����.-�9}?�9u�v�JB�r�\G���%'-����P�..I��9�NLs��!I�>�3�q����N���#���̩+�Ç6SK�r<:X�ڟ���Z�j39��#�D��o��Kd�D�,O-��)��IH��g&7cH}�d~�H�s]��9�����d$�.��[;K#p�DPӈ�>��q�CE�WM�&V2n<�g$b��KC���)�����E��7O���ٖO�ʉ�n���ŏ�s�߽�Q��������&�$�)=����,vO�)�d4�Bm���P�n��B�䔞 �P���H��)3�h��.I��)#�� N�$�ő���-5�$�U����ZvGj5D���rj�F�OG�˦z/���_�ѥ-v��h�3IkS�g�t���H�mf�K�٣�Lu���������{+,��Cq��r���d��^e�:�����|�|�Ȣ#�� F��'�3���$�p8��G��Q2kf<��L�sg1I��DM��B��HRU�,q?����{FHR�<�9Y�]G��~�BC�߷B?B1����Q%���S�RvB�9����q8��z�{��v$~����YЅG{Yե�%wRhO�ۺ-���1J5q���k!LR2d��2�>���ؐ�I�?����tt)���4U$��c���$7�̦Q���;?!�����H��9�-7*$��b�C}'�-��D�TV���# Ib�����FTY���.�ǲ����܏�BV~C۽��~���g�߹_�{�e��Q-[-�Z���r,銑��Yc�OeIx�I#�����kn��裡+TvE��*qhǑ �)%/�+z���]Ej"�-\.����p��l�NM5M}��"��}�CH���b��5�zY�~��9"���0ǜ����,r%Vr�~J<��'8���d�+0����ٮ����d��L���r?.NX&F:f��Yk1G�o����:ۿ[���w���e�S+������ȵ�'o�"�E�BR;e�F����Ó�����g��pz��'&��[�I)�QhPn1S���ȭף��G�[�U��w��h��-�I�dqb�\SR��l�)�I�3�gg�q�rC��������H�����nO�Q�HF|Ǉ����E�1{/��;b�!c�Y1a� <��{(���#�:,��ؙ��{������� J��B���dfұt�+d'ĔS.��N#V�e��Q�'���JSh��}l�~�r�)�:�)E��v��P?�ɽ����N��ӭ���,���D]5V�"�?�nx]I�n_�!8��x�0�/ӪTK��mc)�2�&�w�/��ƽ�ӳ��^̭�ގH�'���Tt8 1JI9)'�I�;�Oy':��W�0���^ˌ�q��J�Kl�j+kߏ"�o������&�ce��UU���}�~��zVߒߴ&,�r���q82�G!��.^��l������m���'��膻�v2^����ضcٟ����e�1���'! 01A"@QPq��?�CtZe�j+k%�D��(HUE~��E��{��BCe�*,kL�af��,� ���������^2��(Q*�rg#��t6^��������^_&;-��v�(}�⽸+d�l����$�H[Q�������ăCOh�#�9�C�������ƺ0�G�Zq8�^ս�EQEQL�!��#�2�I��ʅCdeC��b|F�G�ti�7��D+�z��'����-3QEmF&&&&%�JŤ���?K���tX�0#��I줅�%�=y�2�����F ��\���1f;Ye�qb�l��d}=H~��q��NJ?}�l�����Tq��1�����M�&Ĭǳ�M?���/J/L��ɞ���%���������DX��Z�B�LZ�'%�����ъ�D�Q8��(��rU�ħd���z+zG�u�'5�b�g{X�9��s6-I�ٚ9Q-C3#&^յQ�[QEoce������蔲gD5������;������s�>�}�U2:��ȳ#3#"�2FH�"�hz�C^t#�=6S^�0lZgB� f��s���'�l�CS��::3���ԑ{Y{/5"�`�TF�;,س�T���lS�7B,X�_�]�2+���G���/ά�>51p��E���3�Q8�c?��}�ܖlٖ^q�Ye��}���u���,L��cssb�6,�r7'���L���&<^hYO b�F�����|��F�*���;l��(��Mqyq�CVi#Y"1��hQI�;�GZg^B�,�;g��G$�u�u�u��u���D�l}� �7C�B�_�R?��������#8�㵣�풜W�� �y��`yE�El΁$�5���V,�ݎF��B�G�9�.^G�u'�m?�QYF‘�$+��/P��ͯ+�ٳ7f���ܱ4R)/j�(��,lԢ�x����ٰ�ll&Y}�ؽ���ԙL�o�Wm����ԣSR��������5�^�j8�(�������h�&/=ϵ,WeZ�����).�/�����ܿ�����=!1A "2Qa0q�@��#3BPR�br��4C`���у��?�G0�(���|x������|?UC�eC����P�?,��O�� B�$+|ԫ�]P�Og�9�~T@߫B���5�� �t�k��<+�]7#~����]�a9g��r�j����*ݥw����%���VV�d~EUm�|/�|WW\;��d��D�ο��–���p�1��%�D�[� ƪ�YTnЫ��*p�W‹�r7rm`'?g<�4Dm[�Hi�o���( �r�UR���N����S��4��@Y�e��!q,�6����pR�.6���j�m�U0��Q�L8��Eedf�%�G4UHN�Ol_��d�2�G��6��ڜ��D5+�����.���7�7-���eee˹*� ��Ԫ�0�"T��*�TJ�T.?�">ӧU �B�X�s4m�H�_k�g��7)����s�lB��EW�� Ҩ0�S��TT��UA��;�A�w)�9�� 4ܓdj�l��3�E�k��_xT8WnS{��YW auR�*���O�ƾJ�P੅��au+]�nJk��J�Rp���0T�zm���Cn�U��������%rB�Q�Np��U�Y^1�+`5Zʲ��+�o��T* �� ���jB啢���U7�YPeE˅�²��UUZc@��ʮ�����y �N_���8T��X�N�T.Y\�r*]W.巪�U9i���Up�R���U�J��!�A�څög���{G�D�i#�U=�������G�`7kn��8�Ϙ��U��mC�7�(~Ӈ��,�ض��\ hDQQw�U ����Pٰ��p�9��f�hj�dFWZ*B��u�� �o�T�T���FՌڎ�( �m�?�ި�{V�t� ��,�-�^?��w�������F��ߴ��}�v[/!?��1�[c�V��J���WW�U�s�e�=֊�pŸ�v7W�#(\>���K^�Gt�m?�U{��w��\͛v1�^}�g�"� �4�E��k'������Y����A�Q�����k�ld�u+�=��ѼG��ٞ��9Tl�{��J�Oj��M��Z�E����Np �݈�3�D�Ee����e��Q�Q(MT�Ö��T)�>��ƒ!tU�[wE��얞���Akv�겓A�{͋��44Ml;���پ]���}�=T�;ʭ�2�N���9�'2��Үx_m�s�ρ �(�Tz"�J�4YO*��WuT���q�ءP�\�+�ʂ� #\�'l��J��櫛䡠��U�T�G4�����9��Z~K��E>J��|�4��PW��j�U��(�t*�cPi�\�b��QC�`��|����B���*K@$�g%�j�kP�l[��������:�Ď�F�����Pp�9A �� �h�zWvW��…P��ȈhFT�Y]uUK]q2B�o�R>aP���@/j�V�Q�T{���Uj�T����r�b����W>��\*��^�6��pNn��/��1�!I2|9���#z*�����&���WYWǺ��"�ߒ�UU�� �$=�uߪU]Q^� ]�p���ԪL�c���D�U�|��v�t`^���Z4W]�|^eueF�Ue�~�daU�B9DV8�e껰l�����VU]0f=�����AS�WL,�p�U+_EM��U[���g�*�hv��Q�������\�5#�oIj��kKZZ̮&��Aٸ|�+����nYj�S���.Q����Ƀ��p���W*�>����B�[G�sM ^�o4�Ns6��&�(x��i�Z�%Q�U��7�B�J\���D{��W0+*�W�.e̸�k�K���r�̹�܈k=�Kz���.ɞu]U�*�����&��v/M>JO�쿹��S��(���T�������gi��ч������l͹�v����4�U�$�W��Z�l�S7Q ��\⹌y�T��Q��as�S;��}���}ˣ��U�� nK�C*<���J�̪�ދ��_���Tj��4@����6��UcG���K�P��ٿ� �U@��Ydξܶ¥]r��مEr���W ��*���Uea�]j�J�O��� |�$0—m6m����\�w�D���\p�uk}U�k�(�vǾ��᪓��H�T6MԨ��+��r�/���F��Gc���S�wi��*��������֫��S �1�\�w�I;�Z-J�r��KH#��e]����{Cتm3%s�F�r(���ME| Đ��/�{͞�l��2�]9n�����AկQ�{�ѩY=����ڟ:�Uk�]�P� (�B���F�ŧ���;��|�S�9 w*���S7�����-�U{���]scp�Zc\��A2�-Ee ��+'Ctp9j�(��KG,�pp�0�۰|䯱ٹǫ�m�����@S�S 75Tmz��.���\�]w*� �W��P��UU��'v��������.�APT�*�nl���xR��et�[em�+.�����Wz�\-��8S��� �������h��!AR-���TUZa|,���]Z�E#�J�u�\U�0������H�Si���B�#�z*�L-�J��'v��_+(��@�\4�U?����'EF�/��V�_���H�S��/z#"g+���]��f���]#酷*�U_vۗW�U�\��cl,���4ZB�ê�Zz(!���s(��T.���ڪa� Y�mF1�*�žl�p��I޶�P�Yr��ۡ�0F�fs�O|,p���U��@��߮=Wl,c��C�*��*�� ��C�HP��TU_����Kok�֘[~�*@��,��:B����W"����r{��R�^cU�-��E��tp���,}Pϰ�z�����@UVk�G|altÙ_r�_þ��z�E�hͨ�9%QQҪ]��*���.ep��SR-��U}wcU�� esK -p�(�,Ϯ�6o����JI-6'Ƕ����{++*o��$u���sU���uT��3DsE���d!*��ŕ����*UT�UVW [$aHT2�ʕ��N���Yf�Yٔ��͡�,�WW��llW���Q����էljJ-�r�UT8�~We:oj��V�5|j���܉�C���D΁wX���MA��Pg��\�5�4:�n,ڇL(|�����ub��7�<>[�w%��-�8��VR?e@]Es`����J����L���\4Y3����Y-�_â�[�/t8� �#���¶pW%r��ܜ��_uC�V���-] ���Um{)���P��K�:)e��9]��� e_`��S\kL-��0�++��օ�UU� pӶ�l¥�S�NIvD�����F��� DU\��÷�}�a������y��Ƿ��Qrlz���B���4D�+�@N9�FuQ?��_r�Q[ǮU�_ĨT*0� �P�V�_��UB'æ5��I�.����Q��t��i��7,��:�a�r��ަ]Ԟ� &�gu��.���h�=U���Wr���/��-�t»��|-������|��(!1AQaq������ ���0��?!�ҽ.\�+Ҡz'�*��;>��6F��6ĉ��;&��2��j���U�h�й��L�*�WSZ��qG� ��[������%Q���2�UH1/8�́���j�DD�!�f��H��Y>���,���WA�0ߡ53q]L� U���������VnW��C^��4ܣ�R���znW��z����|zxJ��`�J0�/��n"&`Tqߠv@pjf fS��^n\�hb��J� c�0gm�L<��.�m�Do$c*T�`�`z �%J#�K��l����"A�.@���嚞b p�)����SoBT(F"�(qDo3 k0�;ϥ�19�>f�Q�� `K���I[(�}W�(R�)@8�f�Al���Y3aN%r pE�}J�#�T�Q=jW��4�W���IH#|�`�(Z'N T�Ѵ�C�R�M�Ě���-��Y��0�|\A���������h�(ܼ���E��9 �0aĪ.-�G��i)2j\���*s�}J��k�Cl����b��0��,U�[W�*���W�Pb������%��B��n'���p��`��8�����*6%^s�#f<�/Q}���f�q�)Ĩ�_��R�z����6"0FL�O��|B�Y�i� } ؕ��Eס�^�0g���B�XD0�9��D�*݆yb9A{�����#la���a��j]�@9�1k�~���]b$�HJ��G&�S�E�/��[:���16�̺�)�!�#�V�VNۙ�w6@#H���Jf�IfQĳ�E�Y��z x��Lh��*#>'e�>�c����ġn0���I~���l�2��G�_J �B�LLX2��j,+���[��Z��NflG��E���q&N%�gLz���J�|@V.� �TJ���ﴶ[�~��aqy'���ü@�q�F?�^�����^��eJ��[��o]E����L�Z�PɍSq�^^b4VA�J��m��+h^��md̯GtGUUu=qױ�4�d��e�OZ�A)�yL�a*R�J����J���Yr�̨W>�;�9��R���*��gpf����h�ƫOe��.d�+y��bn⹔L��9�^�-�-]E�����%�X��L��l"�G^��Rߡ8�9��h�A��bJ��9�)�詙Q��*T��h'��jcҽ.3d˅C3�T��y��%B���y�s��"8�E��b �g'�*�d�1Bf� ���>��h|��F����v|D�)�cX����[ �{ר�Ӥ;תL=�����C!T�[���y"j�%j<\T�EKz*�%��\�]+�x�q���(�yQ="�2ͥ�K�S5ZA[If�y �6�����o�)Q��l6�nR�>e[d�y`sI����‰ÄK��\F��J��M����R[(r5�+K5Sڛ�.[�JeA��J�[i+�*>�S�^%1�}���Bm<��r=ȳdI:N3A/�#V�u*�QG��l���_R�Jxx�;Wf���%X�X��2p��uu���������`�5 �h�c^a �@����KlX�0��[; 0�s���#��z���(��Bݚ�]F��{�,ɽKX�¯&e�G�mF &�f�6��ZU/�Q�g�����8ca�aYVݕ|D�(7���#��Ew�E6�=B�^��JaǤF��7�ݖa)���w�ȂT��*��4_��`�2�ق,၎�c;a��-��J��pW���厦OC����H�Ԧ+��dX�B Y�i1�� �ܯ5�Z�g3��n����y��y/l��b���b�L�S�#˵���� &�Q�����'�xOh����L�oR�@��ī��<�p��U���^��E6�'��T^*?+`�����ƹ�l��P����앖�1l�����M�,�Y��k{��� W:���7p���e8�8"�]��������+p�s��A�GId��J�p���5�6��DH���x֡���J�,(�&���?�0�#�2��S��Mq�G�_��tz>�&���Dg�b�������WV�$VW,� G�T4�@�R�R��"��V��O̧����c��;��8�C�a��/�E�T1Z.YED��Fo�@Sqr�J�GL��S<�q��-�C-�pCG�Ds=�vq�-e��Ҏ��v݄��O�D�k�B0{B���F�"�P�B1҉\���Q;e�j�����K�g0�� ��D.p!�J/�>�9�AB��� ����p�����T0�$�U���nq����cx��<� �/��Xn6��M�2��4n����� �?̣�y�!<��y��s��F��sO�!�+�OgauL� .��eԫ��[��F,VfT�J��R�B !���z��?��=��F��Bn��l'�%����A�1q����Q�ub0p`@o��t�\L�3d>J���߂?�"2R:{�d-��_�X���~�jȨ��G�|�o��S�:�h���h�\1|�p�Ġ�3�2\���dz��Adjv#\���y�߆'e��+���*2�LK&&=jW�A$�C�2��]F�?7��.�{_�Ӊ�����(PĴ��}K�CZ�Yo�|�@���t �əE1�گ��o������)B������u�obd+��=��n�/U����J�,�+���_�S�;c���ݧ�L�"C�_�P��rk,H���k���|A �H�J�+�|'�ԄI^�����I$AN�3�'?s5Nߘ���.|]k�u(��G�u���8)qe)e�>�{����l~,��,/G�d�W��U5�԰]FO��:ױ*+f�l�3�]N��G�Q����<���.Sh(�1S-��T�Nv� {������]�`{{J����y�����4e��]���R��L�N.㬟)����?/�~"��aG�9囯㟈8Z�s���!���ց���@D@BB��k�d���A���u�Y�^��,ǂ�Q�����Q�1aE/��.��ߛ�� ����\YSo������)��x��8w+Ǆa��*� �~�����2��щQk����J�K(�� ��9����_�����fS��x����vJ)������u�^��4��ef1% �Y�Ta�-*��+��~�L�X��0��[�K��6��&e`� �����H��=�S�˞0{^���]bRQ���4A�T���'�n^.p0�^wZf���i����YC%)����0���b�L�� r/{����.{"�0wl�p��ӓM<͑� �1�9<Š��y)Ρ�fa��sr��l���{* ��.�.�/�W����t��˰�AAw�}M��g�{{C#��e����J�d�x�l��xM������A�a�L�b�O��^�����r�`����ۏ0�Fi�`�23Œ�I:�52������R��3��s�9@x͟�3�%���?�j�?����Q [��ӏ��Y�a5�� w<}L�᭟�W�K�* k����!�'"R���2�������Z�B �`��:s86�gǨM��_�Le49�Th>w�3�Q�"��c���p��>Y��jm��?�0?�(>�[!�*_|�%!��j�50�fsS��s� �}�З�{ʊ��Վ��I�y��S��$CI8>Y���{�-h��B�)�\��2�Ax���~Ij��Zݥ��0�ʒ�ļ\cw|�x����� ;,MW��8��[��WqU�&�q���gl����uT��-�3 ��`'9~�y��e�pH���^�(T�K�b��4Tq��&��e�o��[i'9 8����q�Y��kuL\���\C�b��q �ΉE@������GF^%�L��=4%�=�;��E���,�D"�͋����>a��}ڊ⥏@s�������17M�UeGP��Ǜ��<��1z5��a�vP�{3+�%k�n�����>��˒)�0�J )$ p���s��e�G]�N弱2�`��`������j-���s*?_��)����\�%�2���m\������wx�|Lv����S�U���2�C��Rd>�@��o�(S�r�1F��Kt�Xiq��1�w�&��Y>�0�H�k��2�&}KB���N�K��&�X}A�5�h, ;W�Z��Á븕lxf��Xky��Ӳ�Dg�1̶a���5Zew^ ]%���僃�"q��nj�{'��R�zb������L��1o6\���h�D�3l�`���2���n�_l�Q��.O��|�.j�� e�A���3�K��l�Q���Z涡������=��7ါ,)�ɀR�����W,:�x%�����DCO�x0�;]F՝K�.YPqeV�=���W�wS~eĖ��GUPn�L8��B���s)t�P`�d:�n;��V�b��Ĩ���ى۷*�x��Q*32�R�4�t��0�7ڥb���2���S��V��q~r��*���0���4��l�Lhy�w�R���,����%C�m0zy��а���t��`d����e�KOliUx~b/�"݈2�����)�%��u�0|Z���T5̌��x,�..jΣao�ɡ`���~9�Y�Z�P;���Yλ�7z�"�n���i�������H.�� ||EW�v���ܢܛ�:�}�X��B�l�l8�Ly��n��<�A"���l�b�-�b��/x��@^*W��ĩ�xfy�]��̮/�t�+��[`�pJ��R8�{ϼ��5���<���_2�p0�3.n|�Wu��.K��`���(���b��P�"�a��� ���6TsJ�Z���Lu[n��*Z9�5�@-��*u2in�8[��M__�d��5�Ѯ�����3��a��_w{EJ�8�k�3�_72����CB�b/3h�����L�T�3eU��i�L�q��ev�eX7�;�� ���I*od�_�����5�_��v=\@N8��."[�/�WWh�����U��۸급q_�U=��&WYG����� :������q>����RC���5���N�f��G���o$���s~���;YP�X�yG�KN���c�2�a��h0�����[`_aܤ{"���z�w��"��l��p��Rn�] !�u���S��`v-�G����Z�3�B�X�TXj��X���M,��-����57 '"s3�p��EO:Ȋ[Nb+�1mKI�T�}�����7tG��@dW�1���*f4վAޮv��-n��e���pt����� ׼5,sS�y��x# ���,���e��+����x���+���7��\�a�#)Ĥ{H3��S���Q���m|3��A�N������X�bV� �o2ݰ�G��5�~��sT�7� Z.��s��*�Q���y�k1��:����3T�9 �ʴ���D�`� ����=X�+Pͣyp����0��u���e�U�HR��/�|���Zm���i�R�s��A"%N\��Rߩ��3=�=_W�����.!uU�����Q��d_�(�A�1F����R]�<�ى�oy���}�t�ge���"|������� ��;|E��/�����s7,��z]eOԭ���=�pʦ�+��>;�{h��c�^������ܲ�Q �v�C�=��y�4S�/�5�`���+�o��=�⋊eA7���B%����-�:b����Q��F�@��,����r�V���1� ]y�pUO/�i�U��A�cu̱ш2�^�������%��!�$�D� &�n�P��m�;�E-� A���}��+�WQ�YR�]���I�r�3� ز]���)���=�R��~Қ��i]2�&����U�kQ֔Op5n�!W����W�?Pۙ�C�#k_2�H�j _����0�]�*��c�~f�-�UR�=�Gg �⠬�̡�N?�D8<����3! |ʢpCz��i^]�(~�^ �K})aiQ�Y�om�������R���꟨Q��o��@�D=#] -e��Jq�ͻ<���w.U�3^u�{�! �9��t���e9�*����T ��9��'R����iM�ً�Kkǘ��]�ΦNs��C̨�2d�����g�@w-|NK� 꽙X�ql�Ka^�&{/=�1�x�z9T�K˂ڼWl��sU�@9��������o?3 �7�55����v�����cK?(�������8����x�>%=�NeRWs�U�'�D1/�f|M��~e�hL�IL�]��w���0�hJ�@�˦��-�ytW�y}K^fz�2�z@-/ m�����@�a���{M�D�X.Z�(發ǛX�(�M+#=����̶K c���Ou�.��c�^`�y��>��f�ݬx�ޭ�K�}A��e�b���*Һ�;A�Њs*�Q�����,S�X�]g���Y�<ߡ��ji(ս�{���I��c��O1sQ�!����ϴ\��k�**j[{���yEk״K��Ghm�tC!4��Y�������;�he��<�u �-�Ɠ�'2-6�u1q(lb;|�F���a�hi&���X9���rlg��n�>�F��M?5�k�a�w�E�F�-��v;�K�C�b7XC�,�ys��,���l�$G�Δ�k�s46zb���ߦy�*<��,=��0� �[)6��r�D�Qz��}%+����`�������}��b9b��_LS\�u��sE"�^��lo��+ �la��#L�Y�����ze[7!�mq}Uf*$��v�/��.�tO&[ύ#̊_9ĕH������ �kr��fC"�(�4]rd�~i~���u9A��K9�gDVoHf���d��Vq@1�U�[�~��l�:��nÏMg��e�\�XPm_>��Շ=������B����_)��g��w�,(��{�nN��_}�xB���5�!�R�NBԘ7[*8��0�5y��Y�h����?ɧ�5Z9�^-Dù�._�iS�ЉH(��,�4>�r���7d�v�QF�Z4��[�0.���p�%S@��C�G�nnp�T������m�T+�w��i���y����&�{s� �Z7Bb�9�j��F>H>KP�2m-h��Sܮ�U���G��>�S��(�J��K���2��F���Zdr��0����Jld� .zKL)X��f�\JQMtV^����b�߂�^�3΀?�a+�k[�kl��WT{��w��u���(�~?�2�c?Q�0��0^cL��/@�s���W=�$�˨�r5�Ɯ�3�\�bh�=F�����V���ƹ��s2t�� =���N� :��I �\�#���[m�����D"ߨ�}�|,{n7Wu�',k�Gi��d>��}/e�u��PH�����K��Hϱ� ��i�ٞ�6��a�$�O�w^��6���_5�[���� �̇Wi� $�� -�5�?V0}a�������i��<��P�v�;�^�Ґeǫ�˖�� �B�q�~���Ֆ��|�l�?Q:�H�%��n��$��"@�>�.�٤È���I�nR>�� �ퟶ>���}#�k�G��� ��m�2s<8�{,�2�d� �� �,}�6���Z����ٟY����c����(�M��#ܧ�[��S$�I��ݦ6�n2d�Б���s�k8��1�l{,�R��zn�zf4z�=\��i�.!rm���3��ȃ��D�d�p�ռ߄��iͼ����YXC̟��@̏����J=O�[��y�` �#=��jQ��,[-�Q�0%g�Ød���O+ݹ�ѷ�XtYC���r�@\�u�1���-�N�B���ݬ���^��"�����ޡHR�,b{$p�X�x�'��m��gǹ���1wŨ1`��V,|��^�͇��#�S�����ɻ��C<;u:vu��-�W�͙�$�3���>d��zl%�C�ճ�lq;�{���aac\�,a�-v\"� vC.�<�F��qv�1a�c�F����N�\�n�����S5H߷���a�X��Zl�1q����w'�2�d��amO1���{!=x&����>�ov]6>� �1�7d��D�.<�c�m��m<7�3;���Z��x��Lm�t�w���t��������e�L�ۄ/��.c�vY��>?�ϒ6YjK�)1Ӳn��"6~��9�r��.`[<˶�z���{���|��re ��ݓ�6��l�c,���!%�-���M�m�����-��ܗܙ��R�p�O�#<�$[l6��KnO'�XXr�c��¹y��s��>����^}��D��^>M�#���^��O�f��!!1AQaq �����?�d�%2��r��%`F�ee#�7��A� {�m|-�lb��,��~?0�-����s`���z'��@C;��L������ d�կ�De���%���ۙV�E� m�2ؤ�u�`�щ�Omd�]%L~!�~�=H$�;,$ĦLVn ��!my��hrC��̞�m�K&1^!C��9�D`M鷚9r�)Bb�3� X��/6�S]�u-؟�S��'#i��+s�b{(I- A�o�.����8�|`̟x�m��%oR��DK���D�8�".E�[ C������XC�ϰ~��K���`,��B��y��o�����+o��Y� ���Z��A�[�oe�doHm� �4cLfs#aK�tZ�oX=d���R~³g�3�*&0?`̉���m2V��ڿ�WD`��j{P�q���;�?�ű��O� ��Wf��o�8vߍ�8���C�x�J�۶_��?�Ԣ4�rF�|}�)�l�uc �l�kyB�O�y9*��.x��?/��QeΑ��ŷM�[_��d����(7�I�8\<�'Ã��O�l3�.ܯ�b)�ϴ����� �r0]N���lq9�x��}���䌢)��"��h����yqǫ� �������2`�,����;����h��� 6��79��@�6>km�v��b�ؒ�d�-($���ff,1�-^m{���=����y���&>=�����{���Gq���_��&!1AQaq�����������?K��<�q���Y�Rb��"�u�=l�2�ˀ��7�A�.^�BAxVp*�<3Ǜ�5���V�_WMX��^��@k��R[�#�17��eȼy�+وS���h5�&��F �@�l}?%Ƒ@�����: �u���_��J���E��P��t��q�l��M��>r���8 ���L��^����o�aW�>����|��p��D���ǋ��l��y�S ��3��6q� ���'8���C��ɸ��1����|���A!<�-����I�LM�Sx�t��:�j AK��Ft���&@���f=iqCB{¢�Y�q[�<����b!�O�2�/�5������θ�q�x�ӽ�CS^G� l�`�;�T�v:� �m���Ƥxx���Ɏ&�Bu��gY��gzJ>q c1����s�R�#��vb.'xm��c8v�va#��+�`F�`q҇������P.��_��pSC�fYI]��^�}^rs�x�̿.%�E�9z��5��9���n�g�r���Sm�o���6���Ġ��7��S���<�C�%����38��1�w�Ļĉ�޺���G�lD.H U�b,:N�66{�K,]�jx�P���ZW ���)��4����7��b�>�3P|��3@:�N<̊�<&.=$�球`�g�x@�޸��� ���g�;ƍ�,����b'��^�� M�?�]ޛ��#�?p |\h�'I�Zq�#�[�Y��5�^b�L�ǘ�d�����Ly ��6r'�gX;f��Qk�(�1�^;n�D��Eo�W(f��%?Xd*�/8!�&�h\�c�p� ��l8_�bl0�)�C�PW����&����r����AGz~3A�����&Y�~'�'1Z�f,D� � )�4��j��� �rs��C�l���"��R���o��Q�u�8�ݹx�pX��s�¥��Ee�a�p������K�����_�"����^\�=c�y�u�%tb�@�q�wo��@��\R��C����ְ`�\I�O&���J\JN��lr}�n��)��?�X3 bE�,Ē�Ꜹ�`j�1ÿ�1Nse޽��R����KQ�l�`��ޱ�D%~�a�’ 5��>���x�p1�K�����IK�]d�&X~.]�牉�5q�/�S\�7�竼#�fC�X�N�I޲G5���9�9C)��wֱ�y2�iw�5��'�?�#���Sfoi�U�B�'M����� & *�c��5&��@�1x����-kA^5=���z� �o'�D���H�fI|]�X��}~�A��k�����@t��RD�<��<���V0�e�� � |c��x��.���M.�w���YpN����ı=��oj��_�*P+*���E\��qQDÜD�h/����6�����p*����A��&���D}������N��~����o��,�LA�� ��ӅM�4�9���[��]�qW�T��b��/��az_�#���6&1�2�^P� [��}�εq�1K;1�%�=�����iKT<����x����;H5Ko>2��b’�X`SD��r�h�X�j���..lOSU= ɐQ�e�_8�@]� #�� �2�RǇ,V<�c�ƭ8�>1�%�{z�x�4P px7�;�kkw�y‘Fs��؈ ������V�����\��ׇ�91tvD㱗����QC�*������R!�"cG��]�4bK5�:����2�� ���k�G���-0����8�h1|����A�8 fY\�^�<����-�n�ݘ�S�2��13f���f:��Q��t-�4iɌ���J�����O���m��w�_9i`Myp���M8H�L�P�U�r��F�?�%�A�%����`���f�M�a2ӳ�2*07A�¡� �Np��@BwA�9�Q(됑�t�&��)迗�#0%cz*���Ȼm�qO�*5�Q4��h7��d�\�1�)?[1��=��x �4|s�M3�8�:Ӽ] ��3P ��g�P7�1������~pZ N9Aa=b"�8� �}��jQ��7R?J��D�|k�F3�("�����1tDf��5}�� ��e�R�p�!�P��L��[� u��/3 ON��e�q ��=�۬`��.ƚ�y�C�znso-��A|c�/b\�%���i�� �㥒��^>0��%}�EQ�� ��p�nL�]��� ��b›[]���mȃ�u0��Iyk��J( ��8�|�7�l�x��!ِV�[�X)�#����US{ľ� �xpi�Ϟ�`�E�9�5=�q�Q„Ln��2�S!�m�}��b*��]����-YBX��'��0����>c�}�� �� Q���ڂW�����|�HM�(�p���=VL(4�j#�}q�kM�f��^�o��8��qH�|����l��c�5*za���Ъ6>pC���i7�?ۆB��h+�^|�`�7����x��@���`�� �R ��p�����8q{L ��M!���6��W��>H��� �����Ţ;&\�����'Z��X�Ĵ O�������6�0�,�X,�3oXq��w�&�8����%r�cB��a@;�@>�'�=���F��������N��mY!�Od@�OtӚ�����Z뙂��"�l"�y"(H��}��R�x#��~0�K�o�C"��R���ƈ�X�^{� U��:�'7�M ��qP �|� /h�F�w� Y�XX������p�rv�q�c@Gք�&��I�j��?�4Z4&KHUZ���DS֋��+�Y����]/�p|:�@����r%:��gF���(ws��e)�}���c��u.��(a85�Z9(0�g�$m�:O���S���@��]� Y��^´µ���0гh\!E[%���@hV�� �)�!}\���=b���1lN�1M�{:� چ���E,�h������eB-B��'�jaj�@ ~0E�ʜc�Ia���U���p�Px���O���P9�?�'"Q\N�7x���<<�0�5m�Q�%�B��b8y5�#P�U+��|��L�����+�����m�+�����8$?G�����K�\�$���^�qd��x�+(��x��*3��G���� hC� �S B���+����SZz�ժ���D?�2�yT6���4��Lk�F�+���O �Mw�/a�f�4yK��X�7���@x��#�_EQ�?&E�r����kE�x{�&�]�}���*�ѓ�@Tm0MB���z0�+75���F��%x!������b�h� �jv��R��o�5�Zk�l���T��ŧ���*���х�g��b�.�I��]������J���7�xqn0���:��Ό�$��#��͖\JT��W��>p�|�Sz� & ���%�+�$��LP�e��|9˒u^�����è@-8�\U=�F݀��Eє{�avo�����T������{�.��F�5tԿ7��Dv>�]����5�͵-�[Hk^q�92��c'�a�!R���bX����'H�#��� �8T�D�^�:T<;0�n�?�I� ���oV�فȯ_�� ǉ��V�s���N� #�b�w�s�!+MG���-�9c�C����0���<?X�֯���(s��r�e|L����#'�\n�"�3v�ߜ��� ���+���D|�0�#�q[�:i��*����ѳ%"��G���d��ڙ[h>L:����X�P@In͚'�!��5�ɅW�JO��:"�Ay���{�:�q�/��#���7�F.���ɾ>0�4�Ӎ#9��� P���"����m�Ͼ�6���;��'���c��� �N�%p���R\�s�#9����1�P�$O=�*���L��rЪ�4{�4�@��b�]������q� S����gB�w0h��Nq �"?9�'���ݯ�YG�YbW���#y ��*;\����R��߇,] >� ȁ�gXBC�>&TX��^2i�@|���Q���% �w��`����,�������;�R�\mR`C-��㳗�$��c1�?X��_���7��&�q�f*I4����Q�|e���Tg�˔Yğ�\E�+G�� ��O�HJ<=��@���[�>0�6�L��&�D�5��:"|�K����K���2 ��ӅT��T�� #��m�ؔ�眐A��_�xkj.��(RA��<��q "��8�x�'�v}f��ڨ����Em@y�q�D�3��/A!���0�WD����+t = 6�!<���P�ظ~fY &��ق �S�"�z2��<2 k��n��a 5:�:��g@���9�|����,i;�!S���{ܿ8h/��Tlr%_�cU7�����=c� �D=us{�7{?�f��s�kS�:ħ O�1��'8��x1�NB̦k;�����}�Lۯ��lr��x����|9r�uH{uXY�7�ƟX�R;����4�j�ŞpC����%�����b;'�����,��#��C�%CO��I�q�����E���&��㷛� \�'�M��4����:��%�H7����JH!�Ox��G���:��!e���q��:�=�X��� $Mj��M��@��  �WpM�՚&�,x^�T�!&%{b����ih"�W���Bht�kQ�F�W�0��w �c@��!OL�R>��#�X�|d�F�f�Z�q�|�6�6cK�6|�R����73���#R��8Hb��/���� A����- ��Z��?��$�yŽ��~�|3��0���f����f/���f�|��.jh����sӞ,n�;���by���C������р��7S��aCY��������%e�!��2���7 i�~ ���sn��S��G7. =")b)�;/Z�1�CU��2A���<A@G�������+�D)��z�A��N2�= �u�@y�}3#��b��*�l�w M=\c��upw��p�>rf��8�`x3�_�\�,�OC�3�Y�����LW�G�����;��౸�Ÿ�_��k-�h��T`��m�!���NZ~+b� K�%@�^��XA.��,���Ÿ&h4�\$�S 84^,�����u��O�p�"J3c!SH�#�:W���7MnUɴ��7�8|ԄYn���0t)R���5�>.HT %^��")1- 4+n��&!N7���X�4%�)8�RĊ�?}�%��a�wp]�T��@�Fׇ�ա�$`���up���90X6l.��5�UT��C\\t+ ��Va�� т�K�ȝ��ғDb3���:Y�ӫP�u�3�oK�1J�u�g��U �w[���(� ��� �%/����9BŢ(��z����֊A.�Ѧ�nbU"T�9�?x \XT��l�i��ZR�/�yB�^$��&�Pc�(i�=d!���_LQH���{�� �h�Q�1r�T�\ R�m%MX�L��Dqk�/��XE�|���>�<��b=d�P=�,]n&� ᥲQ����~�K��Y��b{0��X!�0j�.��§�r�X?���~�Ô��M�2�0������^�&���_Mi�ƣ�>:�������f��,�P�K���dD$x��$�cX�O|�T ����!z5T�i:u�ƄlX���n��xB�i�k�C ��)�4)ue�������u��x�P ��O_|8N�t��>���(m܉�0�UV����W4P,D�|o�hM�G��X�V�������*�?ߌ*U�.�z�CA������v�x��K�]�ypP�]���5��y�4����@h3��P����]a�B6~��Y1�/.�ɼ`��w_4@Q�v� � � T �ߌH��&��7�Yr4���s�S��!"l�)�|`�K��E7D4�2,;0P���Hά�n��%���� J Vl�*<�up���3{t��ל|�`ToF2�}~9��{t�/��XJ���Bu��1-T*&��~�m�;��]x�2P��;��,��^��'��8Dy�9Tn����搤��D�*,s�������]?[-&�t-*��m�� C�M �l���4����*�n����V��tI8�&��CG��� NqV��ol%����Oc�u��������K������1��@ʐ>�J���x��L|O��ϱ���������>��`X"�^��6�l��r\QO8"H�i����Ā�CWG�<�l(�o�"���Ћ�_�5-4~�Z��a���)(F��k��KG�%�ɨ�����DH$k���Np�+"넼�A Uw?8 ��vuϼ!=^A׭X����؄4����k��P��M�q�4��l�}9ˬ5��X�!hm6ᔚ*O1 ��w�!�y���-�$NH3����: ��6#��Μ{�{���I�c�!'�� �9 Æl4C��g=?4��ȋl���b�*j]-���f��`�7��;2�a���������S���@��l�+�!|�� ϗ%Zt /�;���xNF�4����X����(�ĒY���xE�[�M3��;�Mh7Yz�}�!"��#癗�+( ��:�>��&��染��"�ۀ*��R1����`%^��Zq��<�,׏3��+�.�yu!8�7�~�����q��3h�5~��Y�ڀ<�&�'*? �97X@T���N�,c'��%�);�!�{��x|�����//����4����ʛ5��7�F9�� ޱs�/{oj(�*+ �cJVC�N9�� ?�2k����mD����< �UL�O�M,"T/�� �"�j��~2�Բ �b��=��{G"i��kXlЃ>q���` ��:Āy��m:�Y p��O8����=�|�J�:IƷt���?�RAҠ�Ó�H�����r��t��@���Q:��R��kyɱ㮓�Pv#��:�(��n{� ��@�8���p�<�g�ǔeFn�C{��t�]� q�!>w�UM�oHm���P��B������RҰ��t6�B�;��H�a���8Kl �{�U#B�'��$�V��@��g��PQ�F�R��%X�e���� R�D+|�.�I�6����:2(��z� @C���])������۱���;"Rv���.=�b�E��+�aag H�]</�����x��4�{b��� H�^�x��Q^M^��{LU�*to[�<� �����zE<�\A"����¾����pB�j����UU�O���1(�3sihn��T� ���N��U6h���8�]��P�Aל"�4�'�8�T6���|��T�Z^�פ���b���1�m-��59�d�B�?x�X+�������1�,�R�m�q�:oM\?Z�)3�/��-���?�~���T�ܻ4V�h�}���I�B����1�Q�F��w� ¼*U�@v��)*Ֆq��S����F���� W@�v�v^�ÓL7ɶ=���!օ|$���j:��8Ӷ��;ŀ��S��c��V�ѥ��҂��A���V$��7�C�R��H�@߮1qć�Rz����N�9D���n$AF�A&��1E�H��nN4�hS��~�J�z�G��6 c��K��� �`���5��k��6{޽�**�=�w����o���^N;@Y�-��%%;E��l�t���ts��mRR�O�q�"y4.ɻ�_2u�hE4��(/����7���GJ�:{� �o@�:L��Z'Aa�UIa]��uqm ���c�:�6��W��;7�0� �|I��9刜[;�7�Q;4����K�\cEb�{�.h>���+�042Nn$$Ad}�� )�㓍���P�����k!�@�z?M�| U��.o�hZ���^�@Ce��te�����|�:�s#"s�h�L3"���o��v�BQxA��<�R���x��5�P@�_w�H7����C�8@W��@��]oԜu��-�/^q��U���Dގ8��0ю������I�`8�V�$�M��R��R��Y��Gl�*�-tXw���F ��t��0H"J�#�;��|�����������y�[j���GH���~w����t�������3 �8�o�oG;A>����*o�Ă u��v�0J TG��#��`-�ǣ�>�d����^~��������<�$���?��Sd����h�1�-�r�q�-C�i�Rs�q �9/c�ɜ����p���ل]�����5JKv�>�������R����9%�q�� � ^��_RA�*G�����ֵ����� ����k�iɻx�7�H,�d�r�c�N�V��x�`(1���[,�š�:`�.J�R��n�6�X�W�������=���G��Zǅ&��$B t�N69U�X��F�� �&�/���lo!��TV;�&��{ӫ�ٍ��\��Զ<���:˞����� 1|ʽ��Y�<^�ۆͩ8�(�w�f�U�b�N����;%#�9�e�@?Fqm:��~0�`AǮ���X��"�n�s�1nS�?���}����?9l^�� +�s�%�|�0I�.��p�d���d����u����u�:�8��I�k�X�o��n����r'xY��0U��\�bA�b��'٬j!mϱ�?Y{���A�Ʃ���*(¬|s��Z�]��0]4�T`!���qK�Q�^���*HE.�:��i��u��)n� �i����H�4��3��œ)��[Kؘ�m8�^8�pnzݢz�@B�2q`W�¤��]��" V;L�Bh]p�=>�ys�+�D�����]: �xF�ȧ�dF�(|"1@w9��� !���6%��y^:m��y^�\����4kؕ>;@u���g(�Q=`�� �i?ģA�M�]��qrr��4*�m�`�{�:߷�|��$ X�b�{��.�n��}������ER�aL<z��\���j��Ѭ���ۈ g)��@d�qWųY�t2��,H�$�1���/F�[ �5M�bA4cx\cF:�!�l���2&��z�"l_�F5(~'��U����SC ��� �cF)�����쏠w��  *�u�R���$=-ݧ�0R�T���ف$�*����u�G�Xv3OBv -h�8Ǝ�sT�4�u��TR�D�tB��q�鲕�k��Dӥ����JŠ��O�.�����\ L6#��ej'b/����9JJ�P����:x�A��PX��~���҉g 8��l}H�hH�R����׍�������f�nGA���_���yn��b���ac���2U��l���Py��mO���X�]�7������ͥ�B��pw�a�B�T€���&���O���X�6Gq� �Q�����>�E�>����>O����)8N[��X(ز��a�!x���� �h㽡g��ߎBD� ��\-H��)�rd�(�zx�2}�x�.�E�<�1Si��qj��;G��=kπ�m�MBG��6��/\+�°�[�~G &�+�q�$/��X�9��ك���ޕ5O��`����4�!�Hk�?�:�����&p�������7_F �����۾ل��LQI����!�fTGa���5��?�� n_�+cO>7�b� ) )
```

How  to  fix this  issue..Please help